# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Electrical Engineering's [fourth moderator election](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Russell McMahon] [image: Voltage Spike]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5142846921244672/0).

Comment: Good job.  Congrats!

Comment: Just by curiosity, how many users _actually voted?_ I ask because I only got notified when nomination started and not when primaries and election took place.

Comment: Congrats!  @KingDuken 508

Comment: @KingDuken There are [508 ballots counted](https://www.opavote.com/ballots/5142846921244672/0?p=4).

Comment: Russell was elected during 1st round. Voltage Spike during 2nd round. They actually got close to each other, while all others didn't. It's a clear victory for both. Congratulations! [(txt)](https://www.opavote.com/reports/5142846921244672/0?style=txt)

Comment: One interesting thing is that, judging on voting results, the community can roughly be divided into people who tend towards a stricter moderation attitude and those who prefer a more relaxed moderation attitude (among other things). The mods who have just been elected will balance out each other in this regard IMO. Nice!

Comment: ... or fight tooth an nail over every contentious issue. Gloves off gentleman - no eye gouging please (OK if you must....).

Comment: I am encouraged by the fact that election-over-election, participation has increased significantly. This site is holding its own, which is great - I seem to recall that we were a little shy on a few metrics when we were promoted out of Area51 and made a full site. Best wishes to the new mods!

Comment: @Andyaka They'll serve as examples when it comes to communication. Don't think they'll bring back the mistakes that were made in the past, at least not without goodwill and a lot of open discussion. They'll be alright :)

Comment: Congratulations guys!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @Andyaka no holds barred. Pre-congrats on being the 1st to reach 300k votes and 10k slings and arrows defelected

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to Voltage Spike and Russell, we really need your help!